# How to run HTML script that contains LaTeX formulas with escape characters as code in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, latex, ipython

I'm trying to run some HTML templates in Jupyter Notebook that helps me to organise a mathematical proof.

If I run my HTML sript in Text cell it will display an output as I expect. For instance,

```
<ul>
    <li>EN: this is a $\triangle ABC$</li>
    <li>LT: čia yra $\triangle ABC$ </li>
</ul>
```

displays

- EN: this is a △ABC
- LT: čia yra △ABC

I have many HTML templates like this so I want to run them in Code cell instead, like so:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
template = \
'''<ul>
    <li>EN: this is a $\triangle ABC$</li>
    <li>LT: čia yra $\triangle ABC$ </li>
</ul>'''
display(HTML(template))
```

Unfortunately, it removes escape characters in my LaTeX scripts:

- EN: this is a
- LT: čia yra

How to fix this issue?

---

Note that one trick of fixing it is to add extra `\` characters in `template`:

```
template = \
'''<ul>
    <li>EN: this is a $\\triangle ABC$</li>
    <li>LT: čia yra $\\triangle ABC$ </li>
</ul>'''
```

However, I prefer not to modify my script of `template` variable since I want to type my formulas in the same way as in LaTeX with no extra care about escape characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least for the provided example, you want the docstring to be treated as raw, and so your first code block should be the following:

```py
from IPython.display import display, HTML
template = \
r'''<ul>
    <li>EN: this is a $\triangle ABC$</li>
    <li>LT: čia yra $\triangle ABC$ </li>
</ul>'''
display(HTML(template))
```

The difference is the `r` in front of the docstring. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) or [here](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-raw-string-escape/#:%7E:text=In%20Python%2C%20strings%20prefixed%20with,paths%20and%20regular%20expression%20patterns.)

> "Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat backslashes as literal characters." [[SOURCE](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)]

Then the `\t` doesn't get treated as a tab and there's no need to escape.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, this approach has most of advantages. It's not perfect, hovewer, since it won't display properly if some spaces are replaced with `\t`s. So I was trying to implement some logic that uses unicode escapes within math mode (in `$...$`) and succeeded after lots of hard work. All in all, it's better not to use escape characters (`\n`, '\t` and so on) within HTML script rather than implement your own logic. It's not supported in Jupyter.

Comment: I have also posted an alternative solution in order to weigh the pros and cons better. Your approach is better so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to implement some logic that identifies math mode in a naive way and escapes unicode inside it:

```
def fix_mathmode(text):
    text_asbytearray = bytearray(text, 'utf-8')
    dollar_positions = [i for i, b in enumerate(text_asbytearray) if b==ord('$')]
    math_groups = tuple(zip(dollar_positions[0::2], dollar_positions[1::2]))

    for start, end in reversed(tuple(math_groups)):
        formula = text_asbytearray[start:end+1]
        formula_asbytearray = formula.decode().encode('unicode_escape')
        text_asbytearray[start:end+1] = formula_asbytearray
    return str(text_asbytearray, 'utf-8').expandtabs(4)

template = '''<ul>
\t<li> EN: this is a $\triangle ABC$ </li>
\t<li> LT: čia yra $\triangle ABC$ </li>
</ul>'''

>>> print(fix_mathmode(template))  
<ul>
    <li> EN: this is a $\triangle ABC$ </li>
    <li> LT: čia yra $\triangle ABC$ </li>
</ul>

>>> print(template.expandtabs(4))
<ul>
    <li> EN: this is a $    riangle ABC$ </li>
    <li> LT: čia yra $  riangle ABC$ </li>
</ul>
```

However, it works in simple cases only (`$...$` and not `$$...$$`). I'm not sure if there is an easy way to do that in general so I'm OK with @Wayne's solution.